# Make drawerlayout inside fragment full screen height

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I have an activity A which consists of fragments B,c etc. In each of the fragments I have a drawerlayout which has a fragment. The activity A has a toolbar. The problem is that since drawerlayout is inside the fragment, it's drawn below the toolbar and looks very small in height. The data I am consuming in my drawerlayout fragment is available in fragments B,c. So is there any way to make drawerlayout full height while keeping it inside fragment B,c? The code I am using to add fragments is basic so I am not sharing it here.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to make drawerlayout full height while keeping it inside fragment B,c?

No. Your fragment will take as much space (width/height) as the content view it has been added on, it cannot be bigger than that `View`.